# How to run ftp-server on port 21 on macOs

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, ftp, electron

I have to run **ftpserver** with **node.js** and **electron**, using simple-ftpd on **macOs**.
It must run on port **21**, because i **can't** update device's hardwares parameters.
Btw all ports < 1024 are locked.

I tried to use pfctl to forward 21 -> 1337, my device can find the ftpserver but can't log or write into it.

```
echo “rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 21 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1337” | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

I dont want to ask for root password after each launch.

i'm using node 8, electron, simple-ftdp

Do you have any suggestions guys ?

Comment: "i can't update device's hardwares parameters" what  device are you talking about? Do you have another embedded device that will only connect to outgoing port 21? What is the relationship between your electron app and simple-ftpd and this electron app? You want to elevate the privileges of simpleftpd, I assume? What does Electron have to do with that? I don't follow what's going on.

Comment: a medical device i can only connect to port 21, my electron app as an embedded ftp server (simple-ftpd) , i can elevate it with electron sudo, but i dont want to ask for root password each times user is running the app

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with this one, but you can allow your user to run `sudo simple-ftpd` with no password by adding `/etc/sudoers.d/myappconfig` with:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/path/to/simpleftp-d
```

If it doesn't work or you don't have the folder `/etc/sudoers.d/`, you can just append that line to `/etc/sudoers`.